# How do I get setInterval() to execute a click from inside a function when passing a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Object Orientated Content/Image Slider I'm working on.
I am having trouble with setInterval() just running once.
I'm passing a string value to my function `cn.hero('','','','','',0,0,'yes');` which when matched should start triggering a click automatically.

Here is my code:

```
cn = {
    hero:function(r,rc,lx,rx,fx,fs,ss,auto){

        $(lx).click(...}
        if(auto.match('yes')){ setInterval($(lx).click(),7000); }
    }
}
$(function(){
    cn.hero('#reel', '#reel div', '#reel-left', '#reel-right', 'slide', 300, 500, 'yes');
});
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an anonymous function -- what you have is executing **immediately**

```
if(auto.match('yes')){ 
    setInterval( function() {
        $(lx).click()
    } ,7000); 
}
```

When you pass code to `setInterval` like

```
setInterval($(lx).click(), 7000);
```

the code is executed immediately; jQuery will parse that selector, and fire the click event right then and there.

Comment: This is the answer you need. +1 for understanding what was being asked better than I did :D

Comment: @Kolink - thanks.  OP did say `getting setInterval to run once`, but he also said he wants to start *triggering a click automatically*.  The first statement would imply he needs `setInterval`, the latter maybe / maybe not.  Yours was definitely a rational reading of the question. But either way, he needs an anonymous function

Comment: @Nasir - woot!  So do you want this click to run **once**, or **repeatedly**?

Comment: @Nasir - never mind, I saw your other comment.  You want it to fire every 7 seconds.

Comment: The question could've been phrased more clearly, but I think it is clear enough that it is supposed to run repeatedly. I'm sure your answer is correct: I posted virtually the same answer. +1 for getting in first.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing a function to `setInterval`, you are calling a function and passing its result to `setInterval`. (`$(lx).click()` actually calls the `click()` function.)

Try this at the appropriate spot in your code:

```
setInterval(function() { $(lx).click() },7000);
```

This wraps the function call you actually want to make in an anonymous function and passes that anonymous function to `setInterval`. This is a common technique.

Comment: +1 - you're the other won who saw the immediately executing code

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to run `setInterval` but only have its code run once? Isn't that what `setTimeout` does?

Comment: No I need the cn.hero() function to execute every 7 seconds when I pass the string 'yes' to the parameter 'auto'.

Comment: Kolink is right!
You're saying that when the if statement than after 7s - click event
There's no counterability here the click event is triggered on the first iteration (lx)  so you need only one call and that's setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

You want to use setTimeout.  Not setInterval.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: The problem isn't that it is supposed to run only once, for which you would be correct to use `setTimeout`, the problem is that it _is_ running only once and is supposed to run repeatedly.